# Is it possible to order the questions on a Tag by highest number of Views?

Tags: feature-request, languages, views

I'm trying to create a database of levels of interest in different languages.

I'm taking interest in the top nnn questions in StackOverflow (with the each language's tag) as a proxy for general out-in-the-wild interest.   (I'm aware there are several flaws in using views on StackOverflow as a yardstick, especially once you get to languages with low interest levels).

Atm the best I can do is use ordering by Votes to try and get an upwelling of the questions with high numbers of Views to the top of the list.  But Votes and Views are only somewhat associated.

I'd like to order by Views more directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Data Explorer to do this. Try [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/388178?TagName=ios) (apologies for my horrid SQL) - it takes a tag name as input and outputs a list of the top 1000 questions in that tag, ordered by views.

Comment: Thank you for this.  Imo, there are two types of SQL.  SQL which returns the wanted results.  And SQL that returns results which were not what was wanted.  So, yours is not-horrible, imo.